# How to get HTTPS SSL certificate When you use only Front-end

Tags: javascript, http, security, ssl, https

how can I get the SSL certificate (HTTPS in URL bar) when I use only HTML, CSS, JS.

Not any backend / SQL language is used.

Domain bought from GoDaddy, storaged in AWS servers.

Thank you very much !

** Addition Question : Can I see the https when I code in my computer ? I mean in the localhost.

Comment: It's not front-end thing and yes, you can see https at localhost, technically. It all depends on the backend server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options to setup SSL certificate for your domain:

1. By one from DNS service provider (e.g [Godaddy](https://comodosslstore.com/resources/compare-comodo-vs-godaddy-ssl-certificates/)).
2. use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) utility on the server.
3. install and use [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) server.

**Note**: SSL is not related to the programming language used, its more of how clients(browsers) communicate with web server (web apps/sites). and yes you can use it locally on your machine.

Comment: Cool, Thank for the answer. I meant that the users don't have any connection with the service. it's a landing page. And more one question: Buying from DNS provider will always give me the SSL certificate ? No matter what's going on with the backend in case the web do use it ?

Comment: yes, but if its ok you can use certbot or Caddy, they are free and really recommended, as I remember the only down side of using certbot is that, you have to renew every 3 months, not sure about caddy maybe it will mange the renewal process for you.